# Ansible task vars override set_fact vars

Tags: ansible

In one of my ansible playbook, i set a variable for all the playbook by doing :

```
    set_fact:
      domain_path: "{{ X.X.domain_path }}"
```

During the playbook, one of my tasks uses a role, that needs a domain_path variable that is different than the one i defined in the beginning

```
 include_role:
    name: role_X
  vars:
    domain_path: "/a/different/path"
```

When i try to use domain_path, in another bloc after the role, it doesn't give me the set_fact value but the tasks value, which i do not want.

I can give more details if needed

Comment: It works for me. Try the simple example I posted in my answer. There must be other problems in your code or data.

Comment: The indentation of your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"task vars override set_fact vars"*

A: `task vars` (precedence 17) can't override `set_facts` (precedence 19) for the rest of the play. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). Review the role. Very probably `role (and include_role) params` (precedence 20) override the variable.

I can't reproduce the problem. I created a fresh role with single task only

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role_X/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: domain_path
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        domain_path: "X.X.domain_path"
    - debug:
        var: domain_path
    - include_role:
        name: role_X
      vars:
        domain_path: "/a/different/path"
    - debug:
        var: domain_path
```

gives as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml | grep domain_path
  domain_path: X.X.domain_path
  domain_path: /a/different/path
  domain_path: X.X.domain_path
```

Comment: It was indeed the role that i used. It had a set_fact of the domain_path, which overrid my set_fact

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to use the same variable name for different use cases.  You should change the name of one (or both) of your variables so they do not conflict.

If there is a need, you can always use one value to set the other if that is your goal at some point in the task.

Comment: I get what you are saying, and i agree i will change that, however it doesn't answer why the task level var is overriding the set_fact level var